# Proof for this 'power triangle'

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, power-series, factorial

Is there a proof for this triangle  Using factorial as a difference of powers? 
The first row is every consecutive integer raised to the power of n(5 here), but when you write the difference of them, in between any two numbers, continuously for n times(5 here), the nth value happens to be n!
$1    \quad   32  \quad   243   \quad  1024   \quad 3125   \quad 7776   \\ 
   \;\;\; 31   \quad  211 \quad    781  \quad   2101 \quad   4651 \\   
      \quad\quad  180   \quad  570    \quad 1320 \quad   2550    \\
           \quad\quad\quad\; 390  \quad   750   \quad  1230   \\ 
             \quad\quad\quad\quad\;   360  \quad   480\\
                   \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad 120 $
    $ \quad  $  That is 
    $\\ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\cdot\binom{n}{k}\cdot(n-k)^m=
 \begin{cases}
  0  & m<n\\
  n! & m=n\\
 \end{cases}$
P.s- Someone please try to help me edit this properly, I'm new to stackexchange

Comment: What's the proposition to prove?

Comment: Actually I came across one, so I'm checking if there already exists. 
In fact I know that newton proved this. So checking if a different one will be entertained? @MarcoFlores

Answer (score 1):

With the help of exponential *[generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)* we show

> the following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^m
> \begin{cases}
>   0  & m<n\\
>   n! & m=n\\
>  \end{cases}
>  \end{align*}
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> A(z)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^m\right)\frac{z^n}{n!}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}k^m\right)\frac{z^n}{n!}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}
> \left.\frac{d}{dx^m}\left(e^{kx}\right)\right|_{x=0}\right)\frac{z^n}{n!}\tag{2}\\
> &=\left.\frac{d}{dx^m}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}
> \left(e^{kx}\right)\right)\frac{z^n}{n!}\right|_{x=0}\\
> &=\left.\frac{d}{dx^m}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{kx}\frac{z^k}{k!}\right)
> \left(\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}(-1)^l\frac{z^l}{l!}\right)\right|_{x=0}\tag{3}\\
> &=\left.\frac{d}{dx^m}\left(e^{ze^x}\cdot e^{-z}\right)\right|_{x=0}\\
> &=\left.\frac{d}{dx^m}e^{z\left(e^x-1\right)}\right|_{x=0}\\
> &=z^m+a_{m-1}z^{m-1}+a_{m-2}z^{m-2}+\cdots\tag{4}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we exchange $k \longleftrightarrow n-k$
- In (2) we represent $k$ as $\frac{d}{dx}e^kx$ evaluated at $x=0$
- In (3) we use the Cauchyproduct of formal exponential power series
  \begin{align*}
  \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\frac{z^k}{k!}\right)\left(\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}b_l\frac{z^l}{l!}\right)=
  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a_kb_{n-k}\right)\frac{z^n}{n!}
  \end{align*}
- In (4) it is not hard to observe that derivating $e^{z\left(e^{x}-1\right)}$ at $x=0$ $m$ times gives a polynomial in $z$ with highest power $z^m$ and coefficient $1$.

> We conclude according to (4) and using $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ that
>   \begin{align*}
> n![z^n]A(z)&=n![z^n]\left(z^m+a_{m-1}z^{m-1}+a_{m-2}z^{m-2}+\cdots\right)\\
> &=\begin{cases}
>   0  & m<n\\
>   n! & m=n\\
>  \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

Comment: That's clever, thanks. But I could come up with one, without using exponentials, and it was more analytical than mathematical. Do you think it would be entertained? @Markus Scheuer

Comment: @SwaroopJoshi: Don't know what you mean by *more analytical than mathematical*. But there is typically more than one way to solve problems. So, feel free to add your version whenever you think it could be valuable.

Comment: what I meant was that, by observing what goes on in that triangle, we reduce it to that formula. So I was thinking of publishing it, I'm still 18 years and am new to this. Do you think it'll be publishable?

Comment: @SwaroopJoshi: All these aspects are  well known. Since, there is not anything new, there is no reason to publish anything. But don't worry!. Keep on, in *rediscovering* things. This is the typical way, we enhance our mathematical skills and experience!